# How can i get specific column from mySQL with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

```
    PreparedStatement ps2;
    ResultSet rs2;

    String username = jTextField_username.getText();
    String userpassword = jTextField_userpassword.getText();

    String sql = "SELECT distinct kalanizin from users where username =?";
    String[] resultsetarray = null;

    try {

       ps2 = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
       ps2.setString(1, username);

       rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
       String result = rs2.getString(0); // i want this String to hold the first result
```

Hello everyone. I have one problem that keeps punching me in the head. As it says in the title , with using JDBC , i want to get the one column from my database. For example

```
Select * from users where username = "blabla"
```

I want Java to execute this query and get the first row it finds . Then puts into String or Integer. As you see my awful code on top, it fails to do that. I tried to accomplish this by using statement but it still didn't work. Can anyone help me? That would be much appreciated. 
Ps. sorry for my awful variable names and using my local language as variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `ResultSet#next` call.

According to your example code you can do this:

```
PreparedStatement ps2;
ResultSet rs2;

String username = jTextField_username.getText();
String userpassword = jTextField_userpassword.getText();

String sql = "SELECT distinct kalanizin from users where username =?";
String[] resultsetarray = null;

try {
   ps2 = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
   ps2.setString(1, username);

   rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
   if(rs2.next()) { // moving to the first row
       String result = rs2.getString(1); // i want this String to hold the first result
   } else {
       // throw Exception ?
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it really worked! Thank you so much Sebastian. I can't thank you enough

Answer (score 3):

If you know the column name You can use methods like [`getString(columnLabel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) instead of `getString(columnIndex)`:

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
>
> **columnLabel** - **the label for the column specified with the SQL** AS clause. If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label is **the name of the column**

Answer (score 3):

Your are asking for the column with the `columnIndex=0` but the column indexes start with `1`

You could use this code maybe I used some time ago, to query your entire table

```
public List<Article> findAll() {
    Connection connection = jdbConnectionWrapper.getConnection();
    List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM article");
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Article article = new Article();

            article.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
            article.setName(resultSet.getString(2));
            article.setPrice(resultSet.getInt(3));

            articles.add(article);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return articles;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach will be:

1)To limit the query. You can add limit as 1 to the query. I will encourage you to read about it rather than providing samples.

2 )Only fetch the columns you require, for example.

```
select u.age from users u where u.username=?
```

And then depending upon the data type you can fetch it from the result set.

Comment: Thank you my good sir for your answer. I am sorry for my ignorance. I am just new to database and connection between database and java , so i will definetly read about it.  Thanks again

Comment: @EnesÇalışkan You are welcome, this site will be really helpful in all our learnings. My humble suggestion would be to not just work towards solutions but also to look for most efficient solutions, a practice that is always fruitful to say the least.